# recreate existing cs file with changes made in .xsd

Tags: c#

I tried using 'xsd/dataset.xsd/classess' command  in the developer tool vs2012 but could not generate the cs file . I did add 3 columns to my dataset.xsd using the designer  and am trying to get the updated cs file with the auto generated code. But encountered with the
invalid command line arugument: 'dataset.xsd/classes' in the developer tool.

![command tool result][1]

Comment: I'm sorry there is nowhere near enough information here to answer the question. What technology are you talking about (the term xsd can apply to many things)? What are you trying to do? Can you show some code? Screenshots? This doesn't sound like a question about the c# language at all, but a specific tool in visual studio, please tag your question appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

building the project will generate the classes after you've made the changes in the .xsd file. or i believe the command is

```
xsd c:\<path>\dataset.xsd /classes
```